# How to initiate a three-way hand shake with raw sockets in python?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I would like to know how to initiate a three way tcp handshake in python with raw sockets. I have coded a program with raw sockets to send a basic TCP packet to a server. I used `wireshark` to read the output and see if the packet was being sent correctly. The packet did not show up as a TCP packet because I did not establish a three way hand shake with the server. How do I do this? I know the format of the hand shake is

- MyProgram: sends `SYN` packet
- Server: responds with `SYNACK` packet
- MyProgram: sends an `ACK` packet

All I am asking for is a brief outline of the code or information on how this can be done?